# Redirect with params on Laravel 4 not working

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, parameters

I'm having trouble redirect with parameters on laravel 4.

In the View  Session::get always getting 'Null'.

//route

```
Route::get('admin/banners/cadastro', array(
    'as' => 'banners_cadastro', 
    'uses' => 'BannerController@cadastro'
));
```

//BannerController

```
public function cadastro(){
    $input = Input::all();
    $file = Input::file('arquivo');

    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {

        $upload = $this->_tbBanner->upload($file, $file_path, $file_name);

        $result = $this->_tbBanner->cadastro($input);
                    //result returns true
        if($result) {
            return Redirect::route('banners_cadastro')-    >with('success',Helper::format_message('Cadastrado com sucesso!','success'));
        } else {
            return Redirect::route('banners_cadastro')-    >with('success',Helper::format_message('Erro ao cadastrar!','danger'));
        } 
    } 
      return View::make('banners.cadastro');

  }
```

// View banner/cadastro.blade.php

```
 {{ Session::get('success') }}
 {{ var_dump(Session::get('success')) }} //print 'Null'
```

thx,

Comment: Remove the spaces in `-    >` ??

Comment: has no spaces, it was only when I posted the question. :)

Comment: Your checking if the method is post, however your route is only a get route, meaning your view is only been made and not redirected with a session.

Comment: But i have this route too Route::resource('/admin/banners/cadastro', 'BannerController@cadastro');

Comment: ow i change to post and its works , thanks Jono ;)

Comment: I've posted that as an answer if you want to accept it, and no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking if the method is post, however your route is only a get route, meaning your view is only been made and not redirected with a session.